# What is Memory efficient way to replace some pattern of string to other

Tags: java

Eg:

I have given a string like : "I am going to school now, I am going to school now"

The requirement is changing I -> We & am -> are so that the output looks like  "We are going to school now, We are going to school now"

which mean i have to replace some pattern of string to the other.

What is best to to accomplish this in Java

Comment: [String#replaceAll](http://goo.gl/LczOV)?

Answer (score 4):

Dealing with strings is always bad in terms of memory efficiency, as you can't change a string, only create new ones. 
The best thing would be to receive a StringBuilder (StringBuffer if you need to be ThreadSafe) and then use some algorithm to change the string or something like this:
http://www.java-examples.com/java-stringbuffer-replace-example

However, if you receive a string itself, I would just use the replaceAll method to create a new string, as you would need to do it anyway, even with a string buffer:

http://www.roseindia.net/java/string-examples/string-replaceall.shtml

If you need to do several subsequent changes in a string, though, it always pay the way to convert to a stringbuffer first.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to do.

- If you simply want to replace all occurrences of "I" with "We" and "am" with "are", then `String.replace` is going to be more memory efficient than `String.replaceAll`.
- If you want to treat "I" and "am" as words rather than as character sequences, then `String.replace` won't work.  Instead you need to use `String.replaceAll` with a pattern that uses word boundary matches to avoid turning (for example) `"I am going to school on a camel"` into `"We are going to school on a careel"`.

In both cases, you should be able to get better memory efficiency (i.e. less generation of garbage) by doing the work by hand using a StringBuilder and a loop to iterate over the characters of the original string and build the new one.

**HOWEVER** ... coding like that is painful, and not the sort of thing you should consider doing, unless you have convincing evidence that you *need* to do it.  Premature optimization is a bad idea.  99.9% of the time, it really doesn't matter if you create slightly more garbage than an is theoretically necessary.

Answer (score 0):

That depends of your app. This could be as simple as the other posters showed, or it is complex and is an own part of computer science. In the later case, a so called "trie" is build. That works like a tree but have syllables in each node. 
Navigation systems use that, to memory effeciently store the name of the street names of all streets of a country.